# Category theory using 2-sorted logic

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, foundations

Can anyone give some reference text that axiomatizes category theory using first order logic using 2 sorts (if that makes sense)? I have found reference about 1 sorted axiomatization but I also found that 1 sorted and 2 sorted axiomatizations are not exactly the same. I am studying set theory built from category theory (ETCS) so I would like axiomatizations be built not in ZFC metatheory, but in some weak theory like PRA.

I would also appreciate any comments about it, for example, how perspective and useful set theory built from category theory is.

Comment: This really comes across as three questions: a reference request for a particular axiomatization of categories; a request for an axiomatization in PRA, whatever this means here; and a vague question about the merits of ETCS. These are each better suited as separate questions.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Do you feel that if I just said that " I am looking for reference text that axiomatizes category theory using first order logic using 2 sorts " would be better?

Comment: I don't know if this answers your question, but look [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/single-sorted+definition+of+a+category) in the paragraph *$1.$ Idea* there is a definition of a category given which is later one described as *"the first is formulated as a 2-sorted theory in first-order logic"*.